# Funcion que calcule el factorial de los numeros pares en Haskell

Tags: algoritmos, haskell

Funcion que calcule el factorial de los numero pares.
-- por ejemplo;

```
funparesfact 8; 
regresa [2,24,720,40320]
```

Código:

```
 factorial:: Integer -> Integer
 factorial 0 = 1
 factorial n = product[1..n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo que tienes la función `factorial`, es tan simple como:

```hs
funparesfact :: Integer -> [Integer]
funparesfact n = map factorial [2,4..n]
```

Pero es ineficaz, ya que para calcular `n!` podría aprovechar que tenía calculado `(n-2)!` y ahorrarse tener que calcular todo el producto.

Este problema es un caso para los *"dobleces"* (*folds*):

```hs
funparesfact :: Integer -> [Integer]
funparesfact n = scanl (\acc x -> acc*x*(x-1)) 1 [2,4..n]
```

Comment: Hola, la linea `funparesfact n = scanl (\acc x -> acc*x*(x-1)) 1 [2,4..n]` devuelve el resultado con un 1 como primer valor del resultado, por ejemplo para 8 regresa `[1,2,24,720,40320]`, para corregirlo se podria agregar un `tail`

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el factorial de los numeros pares lo puedes hacer así:

```
factorialPares :: Integer -> [Integer]
factorialPares n = [product [1..x]|x<-[2,4..n]]
```

De esta forma no tienes que declarar antes la funcion factorial.

Luego si quieres evitar calcular todo el producto para cada valor en la funcion como indica ChemaCortes puedes hacerle esta mejora:

```
funparesfact :: Integer -> [Integer]
funparesfact n = scanl (\acc x -> acc*x*(x-1)) 2 [4,6..n]
```

así el primer valor del vector resultado sera 2 y no 1.

Te dejo una captura de los resultados de ambas funciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]